# Как играть видео поток с камеры используя ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, видео, потоки-данных

Есть пример https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer , где в классе Sample в модуле Demo я добавил ссылки на камеры с DASH потоком.

```
public static final Sample[] MYPROJECT = new Sample[]{
    new Sample("MySuperPuperCamera(camera_3)",
         "http://192.168.10.10/camera_3.mpd",
         Util.TYPE_DASH)
 };
```

Но в отличии от примеров (ролики на youtube), которые воспроизводятся нормально, видео от камер показывает только первый полученный кадр, контроллер показывает нулевую длину видео.

как заставить плеер играть живой поток?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавили в ngnix пустой звук к потоку с камер, после чего ExoPlayer Demo заработал с ними.